# Returning csv data from multiple files in a directory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, csvtojson

I am trying to get data from multiple CSV files using 'csvtojson'.

1. Acquired the array of file names in a directory.
2. Ran forEach to get the data from different CSV files in JSON and pushed into a single array.

The problem is I cant send data to the client because promises take longer to fetch data and **I am unable to figure out a way**.

Heres my code :

```
router.get("/covidData/", (req, res) => {
const jsonData = [];
const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname.replace("routes", "public/covidData"));


const fetchData = () => {
  files.forEach(async (file) => {
    let response = await csvtojson({
      includeColumns: /Date Announced|Detected State|Current Status/,
    }).fromFile(__dirname.replace("routes", "public/covidData/" + file));

    jsonData.push(...response);
  });
};
fetchData();
res.send(jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to `await` *all* of the promises before you try to send data back to the client. You can do that by mapping over your promises and then using `await Promise.all` *before* calling `res.send`. The following should get you most of the way there.

```js
router.get("/covidData/", async (req, res) => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname.replace("routes", "public/covidData"));

  const data = files.map((file) => {
    return csvtojson({
      includeColumns: /Date Announced|Detected State|Current Status/,
    }).fromFile(__dirname.replace("routes", "public/covidData/" + file));
  });

  const finalData = await Promise.all(data);
  res.send(finalData.flat());
});
```

Comment: you need to replace `forEach` with `map`. `forEach` ignores the return value. `async` `return`-`await` is an anti-pattern. you can simply write `const finalData = await Promise.all(files.map(f => csvtojson(...).fomrFile(...)))`